# Coq returns cannot guess decreasing argument of fix. How to fix my function?

Tags: coq

I am trying to implement a leftist heap in COQ based on Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures. I am getting stuck implementing the same function in coq. How should I rewrite the function so that COQ doesn't complain about not being able to guess decreasing argument of fix?

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.
From Equations Require Import Equations.
Require Import Reals.
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Module Heap.
Open Scope Z_scope.
Inductive Heap := E | T of Z * Z * Heap * Heap.

Definition rank (h : Heap) : Z :=
  match h with
    | E => 0%Z
    | T (r, _, _, _) => r
  end.


Definition makeT (x : Z) (a : Heap) (b : Heap) :=
  let ra : Z := rank a in
  let rb : Z := rank b in
  let zc : comparison := Z.compare ra rb
  in
  match zc with
    | Gt => T((rb + 1), x, a, b)
    | Eq => T((rb + 1), x, a, b)
    | Lt => T((ra + 1), x, b, a)
  end.

About makeT.
Definition empty := E.
Definition isEmpty h :=
  match h with
  | E => true
  | _ => false
  end.

Fixpoint merge h1 h2 :=
  match h1 with
    | E => h2
    | T(r1, x, a1, b1) =>
          match h2 with
            | E => T(r1, x, a1, b1)
            | T(r2, y, a2,b2) =>
              match (Z.compare x y) with
                | Lt => makeT x a1 (merge b1 (T(r2, y, a2, b2)))
                | _ => makeT y a2 (merge b2 (T(r1, x, a1, b1)))
              end
           end
   end.
End Heap.
```

```
Coq Error: Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix.
```

I tried the following approach as well so the function would structure around h1 but that is giving me an error on b2.

```
     match h1 with
      | E => h2
      | T(r1, x, a1, b1) =>
          match h2 with
            | E => T(r1, x, a1, b1)
            | T(r2, y, a2,b2) =>
              match (Z.compare x y) with
                | Lt => makeT x a1 (merge b1 (T(r2, y, a2, b2)))
                | _ => makeT y a2 (merge b2 (T(r1, x, a1, b1)))
              end
           end
     end.
```

```
Recursive call to merge has principal argument equal to "b2" instead of
one of the following variables: "p" "p0" "b1" "a1".
Recursive definition is:
"fun h1 h2 : Heap =>
 match h1 with
 | E => h2
 | T (r1, x, a1, b1) =>
     match h2 with
     | E => T (r1, x, a1, b1)
     | T (r2, y, a2, b2) =>
         match x ?= y with
         | Lt => makeT x a1 (merge b1 (T (r2, y, a2, b2)))
         | _ => makeT y a2 (merge b2 (T (r1, x, a1, b1)))
         end
     end
 end".
```

I read about the convoy pattern here: [MoreDep](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html) but I could not figure out how to apply it to my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a little digression: use `T of Z & Z & Heap & Heap` instead of `T of Z * Z * Heap * Heap`. Unlike in OCaml, the latter creates one field which is a tuple, instead of a flat constructor with 4 fields, which makes proofs easier because you only have to destruct once, and also the induction principle generated by default for nested inductive types (which you get with `Z * Z ...`) is broken.

```
Inductive Heap := E | T of Z & Z & Heap & Heap.
```

#### Define `merge` using equations, by induction on rank.

The `Equations` command can be annotated with a termination argument `by wf <size> <rel>` where `<size>` is an expression of a measure---some "size" of the arguments---which decreases at every recursive call, and `<rel>` is a strict order relation on those measures, which must be `well_founded`. In this case, what is decreasing is the sum of the ranks of the arguments, and they decrease with respect to the `lt` (`<`) relation.

```
by (true_rank h1 + true_rank h2)%nat lt
```

```
From Coq Require Import Lia.

(* Named [true_rank] because you already have a
   [rank] function that reads a memoized rank in the root. *)
Fixpoint true_rank (h : Heap) : nat :=
  match h with
  | E => 0
  | T _ _ _ r => 1 + true_rank r
  end.

Equations? merge (h1 h2 : Heap) : Heap
  by wf (true_rank h1 + true_rank h2)%nat lt :=
merge E h2 := h2 ;
merge h1 E := h1 ;
merge (T r1 x a1 b1) (T r2 y a2 b2) :=
  let h1 := (T r1 x a1 b1) in
  let h2 := (T r2 y a2 b2) in
      match (Z.compare x y) with
      | Lt => makeT x a1 (merge b1 h2)
      | _ => makeT y a2 (merge b2 h1)
      end
.
Proof.
  1,2: rewrite <- plusE; lia.
  (* There's probably a more idiomatic way to write this. *)
Qed.
```

#### Define `merge` using `fix`

The problem is that `merge` doesn't have a decreasing argument: in one recursive call the first argument decreases; but in the other recursive call, the arguments are flipped. The idea is to "unroll" the recursion a bit (similar to unrolling a loop), to define nested recursive functions that morally do the same thing but with different decreasing arguments.

The unfolding lemma (because you don't want to unfold the actual definition) doesn't seem easy to prove either. In contrast, in the definition above, the equations plugin generates those equations for you.

```
(* helper function *)
Definition flip {A B C : Type} (f : A -> B -> C) : B -> A -> C :=
  fun y x => f x y.

(* generalize the function body over the recursive calls *)
Definition merge_body flip_merge_h2 flip_merge_h1 h1 h2 :=
    match h1, h2 with
    | E, _ => h2
    | _, E => h1
    | T r1 x a1 b1, T r2 y a2 b2 =>
      match (Z.compare x y) with
      | Lt => makeT x a1 (flip_merge_h2 b1)
      | _ => makeT y a2 (flip_merge_h1 b2)
      end
   end.

(* merge decreases on h1, while the nested merge_h1 and
   flip_merge_h1 decrease on (their own copies of) h2.
   They keep h1 constant, which is made explicit by
   inlining h1 into their bodies instead of passing it
   as a parameter. *)
Fixpoint merge h1 h2 :=
  fix merge_h1 h2 := merge_body (flip merge h2) flip_merge_h1 h1 h2
  with flip_merge_h1 h2 := merge_body flip_merge_h1 (flip merge h2) h2 h1
  for merge_h1 h2.

Lemma unfold_merge h1 h2 : merge h1 h2 =
    match h1, h2 with
    | E, _ => h2
    | _, E => h1
    | T r1 x a1 b1, T r2 y a2 b2 =>
      match (Z.compare x y) with
      | Lt => makeT x a1 (merge b1 h2)
      | _ => makeT y a2 (merge b2 h1)
      end
   end.
Proof.
Admitted.
(* I haven't proved the unfolding lemma but intuitively all of
   the intermediate definitions are "consistent" with the
   definition of merge. A naive pseudo-proof is that the
   following equations prove each other; they relate merge,
   merge_h1, and flip_merge_h1 to their "intended meaning"
   in terms of merge_body and merge.

   merge h1 h2 = merge_body (flip merge h2) (flip merge h1)
     (* Naive definition; unfolding merge_body and flip yields the lemma above *)

   merge_h1 h2 = merge_body (flip merge h2) (flip merge h1) h1 h2
               = merge h1 h2
   flip_merge_h1 h2 = merge_body (flip merge h1) (flip merge h2) h2 h1
                    = flip merge h1 h2
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution using equations. Can you please clarify this line: ```Heap by wf (true_rank h1 + true_rank h2)%nat lt ```.

Comment: For anyone trying the above solution locally, to get lia (linear integer arithmetic) working, you need to do ```Require Import Psatz.```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added a paragraph about `by wf` and an import for `lia`.